# "PS/2 Generic Mouse" gets lost. How to reload without reboot?

Tags: ubuntu, devices, mouse, udev, thinkpad

I am running Ubuntu 12.04LTS on a ThinkPad E420s. My Trackpoint is recognized as "PS/2 Generic Mouse".

My problem is that it doesn't load/disappears after booting or after suspension. I can't move it, and it is not listed in `xinput -list`. I always have to restart again and again until it is recognized.

Even when it is loaded, it always takes a long time (like 5-10s). For this reason, I cannot run scripts to configure my trackpoint automatically on startup because the device is not yet there.

I wonder whether there is a bash command that will wake my Trackpoint up, or whether I can even avoid the problem in the first place.

I asked this question on various Linux sites, but got no help. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: When your mouse doesn't show up, does doing `rmmod psmouse` and then `modprobe psmouse` change anything?

Comment: The answer is most likely on this page: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics. I do not have time to write it up but if someone wants to feel free.

Comment: Thanks, Igeorget. It works. If you want to reformulate your comment as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 3):

As Igeorget says, you could reload the module from command line.

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse
```

I think you could try `proto=imps`, sometime corrects driver problems.

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```

To make this change permanent ([1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127757/how-do-i-make-modprobe-changes-permanent)) :

> create a file such as touchpad.conf under `/etc/modprobe.d/`, and put the following line in it:
>
> ```
> options psmouse proto=imps
> ```